# MultiThreading with While Loop

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have an Azure Worker Role that calls 4 different services, I want to be able to run each in it's own thread and when one completes, kick off another iteration of it. Since they all take different times to run, I do not want to await for all of them before I kick off another occurrence when one completes. I have this which calls them all in sequence

```
public class WorkerRole : RoleEntryPoint
{
    private readonly CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    private readonly ManualResetEvent runCompleteEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    public override void Run()
    {
        Trace.TraceInformation("Polling.Worker is running");
        try
        {
            this.RunAsync(this.cancellationTokenSource.Token).Wait();
        }
        finally
        {
            this.runCompleteEvent.Set();
        }
    }

    public override bool OnStart()
    {
        // Set the maximum number of concurrent connections
        ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 12;

        // For information on handling configuration changes
        // see the MSDN topic at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=166357.

        bool result = base.OnStart();

        Trace.TraceInformation("Polling.Worker has been started");

        return result;
    }

    public override void OnStop()
    {
        Trace.TraceInformation("Polling.Worker is stopping");

        this.cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
        this.runCompleteEvent.WaitOne();

        base.OnStop();

        Trace.TraceInformation("Polling.Worker has stopped");
    }

    private async Task RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Starting Reddit Service");
                RedditService.GetObjects();
                Debug.WriteLine("Completed Reddit Service");
            });

            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Starting TV Show Service");
                TVShowTicketService.GetObjects();
                Debug.WriteLine("Completed TV Show Service");
            });

            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Starting Play By Play Service");
                PlayByPlayService.GetObjects();
                Debug.WriteLine("Completed Play By Play Service");
            });

            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Starting Profile Service");
                ProfileService.Main();
                Debug.WriteLine("Completed Profile Service");
            });

            await Task.Delay(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

I know that I am awaiting each thread, and I want to be able basically have some while mechanism that just repeats each function once it is complete, without worrying about the other threads.

Comment: Your goal is unclear. Why don't you run each service in a long-running task with a loop? Why does the role have to be managing the iterations of each service, given that all you (seem to) want to do is run each service repeatedly? _"some while mechanism that just repeats each function once it is complete"_ -- sounds like a `while` loop to me, one for each service, inside the task for each service. Please explain why that doesn't work for you.

Comment: I am not following, so you propose one task with each service enclosed in a separate loop, or one task per service with a loop inside each task? Maybe a small sample would help?

Comment: I've added an answer, with the code I would expect would address the problem as described. I realize this may not work in your scenario (since presumably it's what you would have done if it did), so if the answer doesn't help, please edit your question to provide a good [mcve] and a clear explanation for why the simple approach of moving the `while` into each task doesn't work in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood correctly, all you need to do is move your `while` loop into each task:

```
private async Task RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    await Task.WhenAll(
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Starting Reddit Service");
                RedditService.GetObjects();
                Debug.WriteLine("Completed Reddit Service");
                await Task.Delay(1000);
            }
        }),

        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Starting TV Show Service");
                TVShowTicketService.GetObjects();
                Debug.WriteLine("Completed TV Show Service");
                await Task.Delay(1000);
            }
        }),

        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Starting Play By Play Service");
                PlayByPlayService.GetObjects();
                Debug.WriteLine("Completed Play By Play Service");
                await Task.Delay(1000);
            }
        }),

        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Starting Profile Service");
                ProfileService.Main();
                Debug.WriteLine("Completed Profile Service");
                await Task.Delay(1000);
            }
        }));
}
```

You can improve readability and maintainability by encapsulating the repeated elements in a helper method:

```
private async Task RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    await Task.WhenAll(
        RunServiceAsync(cancellationToken, RedditService.GetObjects, "Reddit"),
        RunServiceAsync(cancellationToken, TVShowTicketService.GetObjects, "TV Show"),
        RunServiceAsync(cancellationToken, PlayByPlayService.GetObjects, "Play By Play"),
        RunServiceAsync(cancellationToken, ProfileService.Main, "Profile"));
}

Task RunServiceAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Action service, string description)
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Starting " + description + " Service");
            service();
            Debug.WriteLine("Completed " + description + " Service");
            await Task.Delay(1000);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Wow exactly what I was looking for. Not quite sure why I thought it was going to be more difficult. Thanks!